# Generating an application bundle for submission with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

Please help me export my application to iTunes Connect. I dont understand the documents, I have tried my best. I cant find the release of my .app, only the debug version.

I am using xcode 4. Also I dont know if I have signed the application correctly.

Here is a screenshot of my build settings, are these correct.

I setup a distribution certificate, an app ID with a wildcard mask, and a provisioning profile for the App Store, this provisioning profile is then imported into the organizer and on the screenshot below, you see I have assigned it to the Release build.

I cant find the release build at all on my system, only the debug file and would you say my certificates/profiles are set up currently.

[image: Screenshot of build settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have configured the Archive panel for the scheme with the name of the archive to create

[image]

Then choose Product | Archive from Xcode's menu

[image]

Then have a look in your organiser's Archive section

[image]

And here are the [docs you should be looking at](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your Scheme is set to Release.  Then, Build your app.  If all goes well with no errors, you should be able to get your release build of your app in your Derived Data directory (this is the default Xcode 4 location).

If you don't see anything in Derived Data, check under Xcode->Preferences and go to the Locations tab.  That will show you where your builds are going.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the question, to send your app to iTunes connect from Xcode4 you choose Product -> Archive from the menu.

If your certs and IDs are correct, and they seem to be, then you will be shown the Archives view in the Organizer. Select the recent Archive and choose Validate.

If it validates, choose Submit. Your app should be submitted to iTunes Connect.